# Android SQLite Database : How to query for a specific data?

Tags: android, sql, database

```
public String getDatatwo() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String arg = "lol";
    String query = "select * from DATABASE_TABLE where title=\""+ arg +"\"";
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    String resultsearch = "";
    resultsearch = resultsearch + c.getString(iName);
    return resultsearch;
    }
```

Basically, it searches DATABASE_TABLE for arg("lol")
Then returns it as result search which is later displayed.
I am trying to make it search the whole database in the row KEY_NAME and return ALL that contain the name "lol".

If possible I also want to be able to input a TextEdit which edits arg, due to class extending, I think I am unable to manipulate arg. If anyone is willing to help, I can send over all code if someone can take a look at it.

However I get an error.

```
02-18 12:16:02.201: D/gralloc_goldfish(645): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-18 12:16:24.111: E/SQLiteLog(645): (1) no such table: DATABASE_TABLE
02-18 12:16:24.111: D/AndroidRuntime(645): Shutting down VM
02-18 12:16:24.111: W/dalvikvm(645): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
02-18 12:16:24.151: E/AndroidRuntime(645): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-18 12:16:24.151: E/AndroidRuntime(645): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sql/com.example.sql.SQLView}:   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: DATABASE_TABLE (code 1): , while   compiling: select * from DATABASE_TABLE where title="lol"
02-18 12:16:24.151: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
02-18 12:16:24.151: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
02-18 12:16:24.151: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
02-18 12:16:24.151: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
02-18 12:16:24.151: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-18 12:16:24.151: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-18 12:16:24.151: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-18 12:16:24.151: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 12:16:24.151: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-18 12:16:24.151: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-18 12:16:24.151: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-18 12:16:24.151: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-18 12:16:24.151: E/AndroidRuntime(645): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: DATABASE_TABLE (code 1): , while compiling: select * from DATABASE_TABLE where title="lol"
02-18 12:16:24.151: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
02-18 12:16:24.151: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
02-18 12:16:24.151: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
02-18 12:16:24.151: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
02-18 12:16:24.151: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
02-18 12:16:24.151: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
02-18 12:16:24.151: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
02-18 12:16:24.151: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
02-18 12:16:24.151: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
02-18 12:16:24.151: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at  com.example.sql.DbMain.getDatatwo(DbMain.java:94)
02-18 12:16:24.151: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at com.example.sql.SQLView.onCreate(SQLView.java:19)
02-18 12:16:24.151: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
02-18 12:16:24.151: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
02-18 12:16:24.151: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
02-18 12:16:24.151: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  ... 11 more
02-18 12:16:24.381: D/dalvikvm(645): GC_CONCURRENT freed 196K, 9% free 7469K/8199K, paused 19ms+33ms, total 192ms
02-18 12:16:26.741: I/Process(645): Sending signal. PID: 645 SIG: 9
```

Revised code, still errors.

```
    public String getDatatwo() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String arg = "lol";
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("select * from " + DATABASE_TABLE + " where title=?"+ arg +"\"", new String[] { arg });
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    String resulttwo = "";
    resulttwo = resulttwo + c.getString(iName);
    return resulttwo;
    }
```

Comment: post stacktrace caused by new error. also, don't use rawQuery.

Comment: I just found your revision. We don't get notifications when you update your question, you should post a comment in the best answers letting us know you still need help. I updated my answer, if you haven't solved this already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume `DATABASE_TABLE` is supposed to be a variable:

```
String query = "select * from " + DATABASE_TABLE + " where title=\""+ arg +"\"";
```

---

Also consider using parameterized queries to protect yourself from SQL Injection Attacks.

```
String query = "select * from " + DATABASE_TABLE + " where title=?";
Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery(query, new String[] {arg});
```

Or use the built-in methods like [`SQLiteDatabase.query()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

---

**Addition**

> Revised code, still errors.

You should always post the LogCat errors along with the relevant code when your app crashes, but I can see an error right away.  Cursors can hold more than record or be empty, you must tell the Cursor *which* row you want to read from and check if this row exists. To do this, simply add:

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) { /* return true if row exist, false if it doesn't */
    resulttwo = resulttwo + c.getString(iName);
}
```

If you want to read more than one row, use a loop:

```
while (c.moveToFirst()) { 
    resulttwo = resulttwo + c.getString(iName);
}
```

Also consider using a StringBuilder directly or just the `+=` operator.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that title=\"" + arg + "\"... is a double-plus ungood way of doing things.  See http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2):

instead of...

```
String query = "select * from DATABASE_TABLE where title=\""+ arg +"\"";
Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
```

you probably want something like...

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("select * from " + DATABASE_TABLE + " where title=?, new String[] { arg });
```