# display data in TextView

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, textview

```
public List<UserDataHelper> getData() {
    List<UserDataHelper> list = new ArrayList<UserDataHelper>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE;
    dbase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            UserDataHelper quest = new UserDataHelper();
            quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
            quest.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            quest.setSent(cursor.getInt(2));
            quest.setRecieved(cursor.getInt(3));
            quest.setTotal(cursor.getInt(4));
            quest.setTimeSpent(cursor.getString(5));
            list.add(quest);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return list;
}
```

This is for a listView but I want to fetch data individually and display it in textView. How can I achieve that? There are a lot of tutorials for listviews but not for textViews so can someone help me out please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android SQLite Database : How to query for a specific data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941955/android-sqlite-database-how-to-query-for-a-specific-data)

Comment: it doesn't talk about displaying it in textview @0X0nosugar

Comment: Do you know how to display "Hello World" in a TextView?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for (UserDataHelper user:getData())
        {

            textView.append(user.getID()+" "+user.getName()
                            +" "+user.getRecieved()+" "+user.getSent()
                            +" "+user.getTimeSpent()+" "+user.getTotal()+"\n");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply  use the class object to set/get values, do following for string values:-

```
textView.setText(quest.getName());
```

and for the integer values make sure to use one
of the following:-

```
textView.setText(""+quest.getId());
```

or

```
textView.setText(String.valueOf(integer));
```